# Counting number of documents for queries on a given result set

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have 4 queries: A,B,C,D.
What I want to do is that for the given result set of query A is to calculate the count of intersection of that result set which each of the other queries.

Basically I want to count `A AND B`, `A AND C` and `A AND D` but I don't want to recalculate `A` every time. 
I'm using ES v2.4

Example - Lets say I have an Index with the following mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "material": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my `A` query is matching all items that are of type `Shirt` so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "type": "Shirt"
    }
  }
}
```

And now from that result set ("All items that are type shirt") I want to get the number that are also "Blue", Or that are for "Male"
I can do it by creating to separate queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "Shirt"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "color": "Blue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "Shirt"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": "Male"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this causes to search for `type: "Shirt"` on every query which I would really like to avoid.

Update: I've found what I was looking for - "Filter" aggregation - so I can construct my query the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "type": "Shirt"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "gender_male": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "gender": "Male"
        }
      }
    },
    "color_blue": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "color": "Blue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it better with an example.

Comment: @HatimStovewala Updated with an example

Comment: You need only counts?

Comment: use filter for "A" as its common

Comment: @HatimStovewala - Yes

Comment: If count is just that matters than you can use Aggregation framework. Where you can pass all your A, B, C, D query and get the counts at a single time in a single query. Provide me with some sample data so I can create a query for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Define your 4 queries into aggs and get it at once.

```
GET test/shirts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "shirts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count_by_color": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "count_by_gender":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "count_by_material":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "material",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "count_by_gender_color":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "color": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I was looking for since this returns many values and I need to search through them to find the relevant one. I've updated the original question with an answer.